# How we can increase the instances of Role in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

I working with one Service bus application, I would like to know that  how would  we create worker role programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean deploying your worker role programmatically or increasing the instance count of already running worker role programmatically? For both, you would need to make use Windows Azure Service Management API. For the 1st one, you would invoke Create Deployment (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813) while for the 2nd one, you would need to update the instance count in your role's configuration file (*.cscfg) and invoke Change Deployment Configuration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809).